# Moodle. LTI Advantage Automatic Registration

Tags: java, json, moodle, lti

I'm trying to implement automatic Tool registration in Moodle. As described here: https://moodlelti.theedtech.dev/dynreg/

Registration is successful and in the settings, I get the following result:
[image]

But I am not satisfied with the "**Public type key**" field.

I want the "**Public key type**" field to be set as **RSA key** and the **Public key** field to be filled in after automatic registration.
[image]

I can't find the JSON structure that should be passed for this setting. So how and what parameters should I pass to set the key fields the way I want?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest reading the specification, specifically the part about the tool's openid-configuration, and even more specifically about the jwks_uri property:
https://www.imsglobal.org/spec/lti-dr/v1p0#openid-configuration-0

This section clearly states:

> "This specification requires the tool to expose its public key using a JSON Web Key Set URI."